# Rally constructor/method format errors

Tags: api, rally

new to Rally Rest API. I am getting a couple constructor and method errors with the following code. Can you explain why these are cropping up? I've noted the type of error with the Symbol ">". thx in advance.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.DeleteRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.DeleteResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URI;

public class RallyUpdate {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


         RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),"jsmith@company.com", "password");
         restApi.setWsapiVersion("1.38");
         restApi.setApplicationName("Add Test Case Result");

         QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
         **>constructor - Fetch>**userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "Joe Smith"));
         userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "jsmith@company.com"));
         QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
         JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
         JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
         JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
         String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").toString();

         if (userQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
             System.out.println("User Found"); 
         } else {
             System.out.println("User not found");
         }
         System.out.println("Creating a test case result...");

         QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
         **>constructor - Fetch>**testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Rally REST API Enhancment Object ID to Formatted ID"));
         testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TCxxx"));
         QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
         JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
         String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
         if (testCaseQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
             System.out.println("Test Case Found"); 
         } else {
             System.out.println("Test Case not found");
         }


         try {
                //Add a Test Case Result
                 System.out.println("Creating TestCase Result...");
                 JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
                 newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
                 newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Test");
                 newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2014.03.31.0020101");
                 newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", "Joe Smith");
                 newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", "/testcae/17080774xxx");
                 System.out.println("added testcase info");

                 CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("newtestcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
                 CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);  

                 if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                 **>method>**System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));          

                     //Read Test Case
                     String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                     **>method>**System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", ref));
                     GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
                     **>method>**getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
                     GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
                     JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
                     **>method>**System.out.println(String.format("Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s",
                             obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString())); 

                 } else {
                     String[] createErrors;
                     createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                     System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
                     for (int i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
                         System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
                    System.out.println(createErrors[i]);                 
                 }
             }
                 }finally {
             //Release all resources
             restApi.close();
         }   

     } 

}
```

Errors:

```
Row 40 : The constructor Fetch(String, String, String, String) is undefined
Row 53: The constructor Fetch(String, String) is undefined
Row 83: The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
Row 90: The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
Row 93: The constructor Fetch(String, String) is undefined
Row 98: The method format(Locale, String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the no longer supported 1.38 version of WS API please use v2.0.

```
restApi.setWsapiVersion("v2.0");
```

I also noticed typo `testcae` where you meant `testcase`:

```
newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", "/testcae/17080774xxx");
```

and that your Fetches include "Joe Smith" instead of a valid field name "DisplayName" and "Rally REST API Enhancment Object ID to Formatted ID" instead of a valid field name "Name".

Here is the full app for the reference. The full code is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-java-rest-apps/blob/master/addTCRtoTC.java)

```
public class addTCRtoTC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@co.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
            String projectRef = "/project/2222";      
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/11111"; 
            String applicationName = "RestExample_AddTCR";


        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   



        //Read User
        QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
        userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName", "SubscriptionAdmin"));
        userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "nick@wsapi.com"));
        QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
        JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
        JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
        JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
        String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").getAsString();  
        System.out.println(userRef);

        // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
        QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
        testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
        testCaseRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC6"));
        QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
        JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString(); 

        try {
            for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {

                //Add a Test Case Result    
                System.out.println(testCaseRef);
                System.out.println("Creating Test Case Result...");
                JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Date", "2014-03-07T18:00:00.000Z");
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Some Scheduled Test");
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2.0");
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", userRef);
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", testCaseRef);
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Workspace", workspaceRef);

                CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
                CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);  
                if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {

                    System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));          

                    //Read Test Case
                    String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                    System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", ref));
                    GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
                    getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
                    GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
                    JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
                    System.out.println(String.format("my Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s",
                            obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString()));                 
                } else {
                    String[] createErrors;
                    createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                    System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case Result: ");
                    for (int j=0; i<createErrors.length;j++) {
                        System.out.println(createErrors[j]);
                    }
                }
            }


        } finally {
            //Release all resources
            restApi.close();
        }   

    } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, I tried the code specified in the Github repository. However I get the same Constructor and Method errors specified(in the same lines of code). Any idea's how to correct them?

Comment: You're welcome. Please check the dependencies for the toolkit. I verified that code works in my environment. I am using the 2.0.4 jar from https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava

Comment: That was my initial thought too(missing or out of date jar file). But all Jar files are present in my library and up to date including the following:
gson-2.2.4.jar
gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar
gson-2.2.4-sources.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
fluent-hc-4.2.5.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
httpmime-4.2.5.jar
rally-rest-api-2.0.4.jar
Any other thing I might look for to find the disconnect?

Comment: What lines in the code from github repo did you modify? The lines to change are: 23 & 24 - credentials;26 & 27 - OIDs;43: UserName; 55: FormattedID, 67-70: payload for new TCR. Do your fetch statements use valid field names, and not values for those fields, e.g. "Joe Smith"?

Comment: I actually created a new project/class and copied the github code directly (updating the class name of course). Eclipse marked the same rows with Construction/Method errors that it marked with my original project/class code(above). Haven't even updated the applicable user/Test Case fields or run the script yet till I get rid of these errors.

Comment: To help, I've added the errors I see from Eclipse when using the code from github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava. I'll append them to the bottom of the original question since this is limited on space.

Comment: I copied and pasted my own code from this repo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-java-rest-apps/master/addTCRtoTC.java into a new Eclipse Indigo project, and there were no errors. From your comment it sounds like you do exactly that: copy/paste from that link without any formatting or without making any changes to the code, and Eclipse marks some of the lines with Construction/Method errors. I tried but so far I was not able to replicate it.

Comment: hmm. Can you confirm all the jar files you have in the Library. Just want to make sure it's what I have. I went off of the list on github but I might of missed something. thx

Comment: here are the jars, in the order they are listed in the project's properties' Libraries tab: commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
rally-rest-api-2.0.4.jar

Comment: Nick, my apologies. The issue was the JRE version I had. Evidently JRE 8 doesn't play well with this. Once I installed 7 and recompiled everything the errors went away. Note to self for future. Thanks for your help again.